# Failed to replace env in config using Bash & NPM

Tags: node.js, bash, heroku, npm

I'm trying to use a private NPM module in my application, and need to set appropriate NPM access tokens so that third-party tools (Heroku and CI) can access, and install the module.

I have the following line set in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
```

and then in the `/path/to/app/.npmrc` I have

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

However, whenever I open my terminal, I get the following error on startup:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    at /Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:429:13
    at String.replace (native)
    at envReplace (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:424:12)
    at parseField (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:400:7)
    at /Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:338:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Conf.add (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:337:23)
    at ConfigChain.addString (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:325:10)
    at /Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:76:16
/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:29
throw new Error('npm.load() required')
^

Error: npm.load() required
at Object.npm.config.get (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:29:11)
at exit (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:58:40)
at process.errorHandler (/Users/marcthomas/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:385:3)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at process.emit (events.js:169:7)
at process._fatalException (node.js:221:26)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.2.1 --silent` to unset it.
```

However, running `echo $NPM_TOKEN` returns the correct token, so the variable definitely exists.

If I run `source ~/.bash_profile` the error disappears, and I can install as normal.

Any help appreciated as I'm bashing my head against a wall at this problem!

Comment: please run `set | grep NPM_TOKEN` from the same shell that you are running node, to see that your `.bash_profile` is run, and that NPM_TOKEN is set.

Comment: For me I found out that you shouldn't use an already opened term window after setting the token. Use the same window you set the token with or open a fresh window afterwards not another, previously opened one.

Answer (score 46):

The fix for me was moving `export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"` before my nvm stuff in `.bash_profile`

from

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
```

to

```
export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Comment: This is great, this was my problem.  Once rearranging my export to above my nvm.sh script source it solved the issue when opening a terminal window.  Beauty!

Comment: I've done this but I still am getting this error. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 11):

## Actually proper solution

Update your CI deployment configuration:

```bash
npm config set '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken' "${NPM_TOKEN}"
npm publish
```

Remove this line from the `.npmrc` file:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

### Example build config

You can see this solution used in practice in one of my GitHub repositories: https://github.com/Jezorko/lambda-simulator/blob/5882a5d738060c027b830bcc2d58824c5d27942b/.github/workflows/deploy.yml#L26-L27

The encrypted environment variable is an NPM token.

## Why the other "solutions" are mere workarounds

I've seen answers here and under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015748/npm-failed-to-replace-env-in-config-npm-token) that recommend simply removing the variable setting line or `.npmrc` file entirely.

**Thing is, the `.npmrc` file might not be ignored by your VCS system and modifying it might lead to accidental pushes to your project's repository. Additionally, the file may contain other important settings.**

The problem here is that `.npmrc` does not allow defaults when setting up environment variables. For example, if the following syntax was allowed, the issue would be non-existent:

`//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN:-undefined}`

Answer (score 2):

**For Windows 10 users**

1. run `set NPM_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` in your **cmd** prompt **OR** set it as a environment variable
   [image]
2. edit `.npmrc`, a pair of `%` should be used, good to run `npm i` now.

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
```

or (if above one doesn't work)

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=%NPM_TOKEN%
```

**Btw, if you need a fallback solution:**

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=%NPM_TOKEN% //<-- depends on your need
//your-corp-registry-url/:_authToken=%YOUR_CORP_TOKEN% //<-- depends on your need
@your-corp:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/path-of-your-corp
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com  //<-- fallback registry
```

Comment: Thanks! step 1 was enough to resolve my issue!

Answer (score -1):

I am also getting the same problem when writing any command related to npm. So I solved by **node or nodemon** . so when you want to start your server use the **node** and when you want to install any package just remove this and then install it will work.

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN:-undefined}
```

It will work in both react and node.js for me.
Run react also by node by creating own server.js file like in node.js
By this, I successfully deployed my application on Heroku
and in production give your env variable on the server where you are deploying and in your own machine put it in .bash_profile and put it in .gitignore

```
export NPM_TOKEN="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
```

Answer (score -6):

In your case you have to do this `rm -f ./.npmrc` . This worked for me.

Comment: You definitely do not want to remove your `.nprmrc` - this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45200292/3291343

Comment: The .npmrc file can include information required by npm for accessing npm private repos. So don't blindly remove the .npmrc file